# Windows 10 Event Viewer ID description problem

Tags: windows-10, event-log, event-viewer

I've looked at so many articles in the past year without finding an answer, I'm starting to go crazy...

I do a lot of application support and use the Event Viewer on a regular basis. On any machine but mine, when I look at an event with Event ID 0, the "data" part of that entry is shown in the General tab of the viewer. This is the default behavior that I like. On my laptop, however, for about a year now, Event ID 0 shows as "The operation completed successfully." I no longer see the "data" part of the event in the General section of the window.

[Example of the annoying message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sViVV.png)

The only thing I can think of, is that I added a custom description (or definition) for Event ID 0. But frankly, I don't know how I did it, if that is the case. I want to go back to seeing the "data" in there, rather than this useless message.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

While not a "fix" to the problem, I have what may be a workaround for you.

First, I can confirm that **I have experienced it also**--and it's been **on MORE than one computer**. But it has been limited to **only some apps** ("sources", in event viewer parlance). So I am assuming it's THEIR doing rather than ours. Your situation may be different.

But second, and until you may find a better solution, I will note also that there may well BE a useful message for you to see. **If you click on the Details tab above that message, the "friendly view" of the details will readily show what the "real" message is that underlies that log entry.**

See this screenshot showing a Postgres startup message that was hidden under such an "operation completed successfully" log entry.

[image: Image of postgres message, only in "details"]

I have seen it and other apps/sources work this way for such startup status messages, failures, errors, and more.

Like you, I lament that we should have to know to do that. It feels to me like the folks creating the code that create the event log entry are making some choice that leads to this behavior. At least now I know that I can SEE the info they are trying to share, albeit via what seems a poor choice.